# How to handle lots of ports with AWS Network load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an application that has to answer to lots of ports (hundreds).
With an AWS Network Loadbalancer, is it necessary to create one target group by port ?

I can only set one port when creating target group.

Maybe there is no limit in number of target groups associated or related to a load balancer, but what I fear is the time needed to change all thoses target groups, when I need to add or remove EC2 instances of this application.

Is there another way to manage all these ports, with a managed loadbalancer ?

Comment: The first question seems to be *why are you opening hundreds of ports?*  I wonder if you are trying to solve the correct problem.

Comment: @Michael My application require to dedicate one port by customer. For years I'm in my job, I've seen that several major operators are doing the same for that kind of application. I can't change that, unfortunately.

Comment: The port a network load balancer listens on is an attribute of the *listener* (front end) rather than of the *target group* (back end).  The limit of listeners per balancer is 50 and does not appear to be a limit that you can increase. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-limits.html